# R Studio Shiny Server - $ operator is invalid when using SQL scripts

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rodbc

Anyone run in to his problem? I have a shiny app that uses SQL files to import data from MS SQL server using the RODBC package. I've narrowed down the problem to here in the **server.R** file:

```
ch <- odbcConnect(dsn = xxxxxx)
iQry <- readChar("LeaderDashInd.sql", file.info("LeaderDashInd.sql")$size, T)
oQry <- readChar("LeaderDashOrg.sql", file.info("LeaderDashOrg.sql")$size, T)
iDat <- sqlQuery(channel = ch, query = iQry, stringsAsFactors = F)
oDat <- sqlQuery(channel = ch, query = oQry, stringsAsFactors = F)
odbcClose(ch)

# PREPROCESSING --------------------------
cy <- max(iDat$CampYear)
```

The app stops at the last line above and gives... Error in iDat$CampYear : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I know this chunk is the problem because when I have the same app run off imported csv files, it works.

A couple things to note:

1. This code runs first in the server.R file outside the shinyServer function.
2. **The app runs fine when launched from my workstation through R Studio**. It only stops working when run on our Shiny Server installation.
3. Shiny packages are up to date and shiny server is a recent install.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `class(iDat)`? What type of query are you running exactly? Doesn't sound like you are getting a data.frame back. Maybe you are getting an error.

Comment: If it works on your workstation but not on the server, it makes me think that "LeaderDashInd.sql" may not be in the working directory on the server.

Comment: iDat is a data frame. But yes, *on the server version* it might not be for some inexplicable reason. Based on some other troubleshooting I've been doing it seem like this is the crux of the problem... Not importing as a data frame. Yes SQL files are in the wd on the server.

Answer (score 0):

FYI... changing the SQL query to a stored procedure and then calling the stored procedure with `RODBC::sqlQuery` fixed the problem. The *$ operator invalid* error was coming up because the query was not running and returning an empty vector.

Still doesn't explain why the stand alone query using `readChar` doesn't work in Shiny Server but hey... its a fix.